# Is IMPLY enough for this function?

Tags: code-golf

Given a boolean function with inputs, check if it's possible to only use [IMPLY gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMPLY_gate) to express it.

There's no extra limitation on how you use this gate, and you can use each input for any amount of times. See examples below:

\$\begin{matrix}
\text{Expression}&&&&&\text{Solution}&\text{Your output}\\
a&0&0&1&1&a&\text{true}\\
b&0&1&0&1&b&\text{true}\\
a\vee b&0&1&1&1&\left(a\rightarrow b\right)\rightarrow b&\text{true}\\
\neg a&1&1&0&0&-&\text{false}\\
a\wedge b&0&0&0&1&-&\text{false}\\
1&1&1&1&1&a\rightarrow a&\text{true}
\end{matrix}\$

> This actually checks if there is one input that make the output of function true as long as it's true. Proof is left as an exercise.

Input can be taken as a function, a boolean array of length \$2^n\$, or any convenient format. Shortest code wins.

Comment: What format should people take the input in?

Comment: Can I take input as a \$2^n\$ (\$n\$-dimensional) array where each axis represents one variable?

Comment: How does imply gate work? For example, may I connect nothing to gate's input? Will its input becomes false automatically? And then we can use \$ a \implies 0 \$ to do something if so.

Comment: @tsh Nope every input is connected

Comment: It's a beautiful table; nicest display of testcases I've seen yet!

Comment: So the input is a function that has n boolean parameters?  I don’t understand how the test cases map to that?

Comment: @Jonah All examples have \$n=2\$ because that fits the table

Comment: Can you spell out what the 4 numbers correspond to?  Also in the first example how is the single value `a` supposed to be implemented by imply?  I’m probably missing something obvious but I’m still not getting it

Comment: @Jonah The four numbers are the evaluation of the expression for the four possible inputs `ab`: `00`, `01`, `10`, `11`, in that order. The single value solutions seem to mean that we are taking the vacuous truth that if the logical expression can be implemented with no gates then it can be implemented with only imply gates. These do seem like they should be in the question body, though.

Comment: @Jonah Actually it uses 0 IMPLYs, though you can also use \$\left(a\rightarrow a\right)\rightarrow a\$

Comment: So are we expected to take functions of more than 2 variables?  This is a little unclear to me.

Comment: @WheatWizard Yes, bu not function of 0 variable(avoids some edge cases)

Comment: I can't prove the spoiler but I found `((b->a)->c)->((c->(b->a))->a)` which has a truth table that I didn't expect.

Comment: What is IMPLY gate? You need to include that in the challenge rather than relying on an external link.

Comment: @l4m2 Fwiw, I thought this was a very interesting challenge (once I understood it), and I think it's worth making it more clear to re-open it.

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
oJ’|/‘nL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/f61HDzBr9Rw0z8nz@H27XjPz/P9pAx0DHUMcwVicaRBvAWRAxQ7CYAVjMACprCJeF6tAxhOoEAA)

*-1 because it came to me in a dream... to use `>`, which would not have worked at all, but it still got me thinking*

Same input format as hyper-neutrino's solution and also uses OP's spoiler.

```
oJ          Replace each 0 in the input with its index in the input,
  ‘         then decrement each.
oJ‘         We now have every bitmask which yields false, and some extra zeroes.
   |/       Reduce by bitwise OR.
     ‘      Incremented,
      nL    is it not equal to the length?
```

> The bitwise OR of the false bitmasks is 1 less than the length (the length being a power of 2) iff each input variable can produce false while being true.

A rough proof of the spoiler:

> **It is necessary for the function to be implied by a variable:**
>  
>  An expression composed of just implications is either a variable or the implication of two such expressions. In butchered BNF:
>  $$\text{<E>} \text{ ::= } \text{<Var>} \text{ | } \text{<E>} \rightarrow \text{<E>}$$
>  Clearly, any expression consisting of a lone variable is true precisely when that variable is true.
>  
>  An implication \$a \rightarrow b\$, furthermore, is true at least when \$b\$ is true, for any expression \$b\$. If \$b\$ satisfies the property that some variable implies it, so does \$a \rightarrow b\$. Therefore this is true of any implication of variables, any implication of implications of variables, and so on.
>  
>  **It is sufficient for the function to be implied by a variable:**
>  
>  There is no function satisfying the condition which cannot be expressed only in implicatures.
>  Let's call the variable which implies the function \$a\$. If we look only at the cases in which \$¬a\$, \$¬b\$ can be written \$b \rightarrow a\$. From there, considering that
>  $$x \vee y \iff (x \rightarrow y) \rightarrow y$$
>  we have
>  $$x \wedge y \iff ¬(¬x \vee ¬y) \iff (((x \rightarrow a) \rightarrow (y \rightarrow a)) \rightarrow (y \rightarrow a)) \rightarrow a$$
>  hence any function can be expressed in nothing but implicatures presupposing a known false variable, and such an expression without the presupposition is the disjunction of any function and an additional variable.

Comment: For me it's the other way around - I worked out that the second spoiler implies that any variable implying the function implied that the function can be written as a combination of implications, but I don't see how the reverse is true yet.

Comment: @Neil Edited to explain more fully (I hope)

Comment: Ah yes, it was the fact that `(a->b)->(a->(c->b))` that I was missing.

Comment: Writing \$x∧y\$ as \$x→\left(y→⊥\right)\$ may be more direct, though

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
;2/ƬḊm2ȦƊ€Ẹ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/aSP/Ymoc7unKNTiw71vWoac3DXTv@//9voGOoA8KGEBoA)

-2 bytes thanks to Unrelated String

Still looking to shorten this with a more intelligent way of applying OP's spoiler. Accepts input as a length \$2^n\$ list in the order of `[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]` (standard bit mask enumeration). Working on a proof first though.

Comment: `s2F€$` -> `;2/`?

Comment: @UnrelatedString Oh yeah good catch, I've never really used n-wise reduce much. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 14 bytes

```
⊙↨⊖Ｌθ²⌊Φθ＆μＸ²κ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYixCoMwEEB/5cYLXKG6dlJKpxbcxSHEox5NToxppV9/Fac@3ltemHwOs49mXRYt2OgXW78yXjlkTqyFR7yzPsuEi3ME9d5DVNI74U1i4YwLQStlk5UbHTERdPO275rg5Q4uZn1fEZwPq3@HwU6f@AM) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a binary array of length 2ⁿ and outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for implied, nothing if not. Explanation:

```
    θ           Input array
   Ｌ            Length
  ⊖             Decremented
 ↨   ²          Convert to base 2
⊙               Does any bit satisfy
        θ       Input array
       Φ        Filtered where
          μ     Inner index
         ＆      Bitwise And
           Ｘ²   2 raised to power
             κ  Outer index
      ⌊         Does not contain zero
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Port of [Unrelated String's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230887/58974) 'cause I genuinely don't have the first clue what the challenge is asking us to do.

```
ÊÉ¦UËÉ©EÃr|
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=ysmmVcvJqUXDcnw&input=WzAsMCwxLDFd) or [run all test cases](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=ysmmVcvJqUXDcnw&input=W1swLDAsMSwxXSxbMCwxLDAsMV0sWzAsMSwxLDFdLFsxLDEsMCwwXSxbMCwwLDAsMV0sWzEsMSwxLDFdLFswLDEsMCwxLDEsMSwwLDFdXQotbQ)

```
ÊÉ¦UËÉ©EÃr|     :Implicit input of array U
Ê               :Length
 É              :Subtract 1
  ¦             :Not equal to
   UË           :Map each element in U at 0-based index E
     É          :  Subtract 1
      ©E        :  Logical AND with E
        Ã       :End map
         r|     :Reduce by bitwise OR
```